# Como fazer a comunicação entre java em prolog?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, prolog

Bom dia!

Preciso desenvolver um sistema especialista como trabalho da faculdade. Pensei em fazê-lo usando java para criar a interface e prolog como motor de inferência e base de fatos. Mas os links que achei sobre uma biblioteca JPL estão quebrados e não sei como fazer a comunicação entre essas duas tecnologias. Alguém pode dar uma luz?

ps: Uso ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma alternativa é a biblioteca 
[tuProlog](http://apice.unibo.it/xwiki/bin/view/Tuprolog/) usei na para fazer um joguinho de xadrez usando java para a interface e prolog como motor de inferência

No arquivo Java teria algo como:

```
static Prolog engine = new Prolog();
engine.setTheory(new Theory(new FileInputStream("prolog/xadrez.pl")));
engine.solve("iniciarJava.");
info = engine.solve("mostrartab(T).");
```

No arquivo prolog as regras e lógica:

```
mostrartab(T):-
  findall((P,Cl,(L,C)),p_atual(P,Cl,(L,C)),T).

/*carrega a base de fatos que será o tabuleiro durante a partida*/
iniciarJava:- retractall(p_atual(_,_,(_,_))),retractall(cemiterio(_,_)),
assert(p_atual('T','B',(1,1))),assert(p_atual('H','B',(1,2))),
assert(p_atual('B','B',(1,3))),assert(p_atual('Q','B',(1,4))),
assert(p_atual('K','B',(1,5))),assert(p_atual('B','B',(1,6))),
assert(p_atual('H','B',(1,7))),assert(p_atual('T','B',(1,8))),
assert(p_atual('T','W',(8,1))),assert(p_atual('H','W',(8,2))),
assert(p_atual('B','W',(8,3))),assert(p_atual('Q','W',(8,4))),
assert(p_atual('K','W',(8,5))),assert(p_atual('B','W',(8,6))),
assert(p_atual('H','W',(8,7))),assert(p_atual('T','W',(8,8))),
assert(p_atual('P','B',(2,1))),assert(p_atual('P','B',(2,2))),
assert(p_atual('P','B',(2,3))),assert(p_atual('P','B',(2,4))),
assert(p_atual('P','B',(2,5))),assert(p_atual('P','B',(2,6))),
assert(p_atual('P','B',(2,7))),assert(p_atual('P','B',(2,7))),
assert(p_atual('P','W',(7,1))),assert(p_atual('P','W',(7,2))),
assert(p_atual('P','W',(7,3))),assert(p_atual('P','W',(7,4))),
assert(p_atual('P','W',(7,5))),assert(p_atual('P','W',(7,6))),
assert(p_atual('P','W',(7,7))),assert(p_atual('P','W',(7,8))),
assert(p_atual(' ',' ',(_,_))).
```

Para pegar o retorno do prolog:

```
info.getVarValue("T")
```

Comment: pra funcionar é só colocar o .jar como biblioteca do projeto?

Comment: isso, aí você da import nas classes do tuProlog

Comment: no caso, tem o 2p.jar e tuprolog.jar. o 2p.jar contém alguns pacotes do tuprolog.jar, acho que seria mais recomendado adicionar só o 2p.jar então ne?

Comment: Aí vai depender de quais pacotes você vai utilizar, se o 2p.jar tiver o que você necessita usa só ele.